# Integrating applications with projects in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, web-services

We need to integrate our application with a client's applications, and this integration will happen through WebServices.

We will have to instantiate different classes depending on which release the client is on. The thing is, I don't know how other companies do that, we were thinking about some dynamic assembly loading for code readability or manage this through pre-processor directives.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I might not understand very well your question (maybe you could add some more details) but doesn't the Factory [pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) suit your needs?

**EDIT**: This may help too: http://martinfowler.com/articles/enterprisePatterns.html

Comment: I agree - from the basic details provided it would seem you would find the most use out of the factory pattern.